# Django sorting by date returns wrong sorting order

Tags: mysql, django, sql-order-by

I have a query like this:

```
Pedido.objects.filter(...).aggregate(...).values('dia_pedido').annotate(...).order_by('dia_pedido')
```

The field 'dia_pedido' is of Date type.
Data is not being displayed in the correct order:

```
(...)
25/08/2022

26/08/2022

30/08/2022

01/09/2022

02/09/2022

28/06/2022

30/06/2022

01/07/2022
```

The last 3 lines above shouldn't be there, as June and July come before August and September. What could be happening?

I'm using Django 4.0.1 and MySQL 8.0.30.

Answer (score -1):

think mistake in type of date, mb american variant

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).